# Verify the identity given in textbook

Tags: trigonometry

Need help with solving this identity.

${(\tan\alpha-\cot\alpha)^2 ={\ 3 \over \ 1-sin^6\alpha-cos^6\alpha}}$

If anyone could help I would be thankful.

Comment: I tried to do this with tan and cot (tan+cot)^2 = tan^2 + 2tan*cot + cot^2 and tried to expand it but I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: Did you try rewriting $\tan$ and $\cot$ in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$? This will be necessary at some point as the right-hand side only uses $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: Yes I did try it but the other side has sin and cos in the power of 6 and I got stuck again.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$(\sin^2x)^3+(\cos^2x)^3=(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)^3-3\sin^2x\cos^2x(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)=?$$

$$2\sin x\cos x=\sin2x$$

$$\cot x-\tan x=\dfrac{2\cos2x}{\sin2x}=2\cot2x$$

Comment: In my school I learned that we try to get the left side to match with the right so can you explain it to me how can I get ${(\tan\alpha-\cot\alpha)^2}$ to match with the right side ${\ 3 \over \ 1-sin^6\alpha-cos^6\alpha}$

Comment: @EndritShala, Not required to derive one from the other. Its sufficient to reach at the same expression from both sides